# Cluj-Napoca Sitecore Meetup: Sitecore 9

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

- **Date/Time (local):** Tuesday, 5 December 2017 at 5:45pm
- **Date/Time (UTC):** Tuesday, 5 December 2017 at 3:30pm
- **Location:** Endava, United Business Center Tower
  Cluj-Napoca, Strada Al. Vaida Voievod nr. 51, Cluj-Napoca, Romania
- **Event Details:** [Meetup Details and RSVP](https://www.meetup.com/Cluj-Napoca-Sitecore-Meetup/events/245280357/)
- **Contact:** [Meetup Organizers](https://www.meetup.com/Cluj-Napoca-Sitecore-Meetup/)
- **Description:** Sitecore 9 was released. As we could not go to the presentations in Las Vegas, we are using this opportunity ahead of Christmas to acknowledge some of the changes that the new edition brings. Join us into last meetup this year to discuss about Sitecore and the new features, as well as get in the mood for THE LAST JEDI :).

Comment: Sorry, saw this too late. On the other hand, try to submit this in advance next time :)

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko sure will do, just that only yesterday I've noticed there is a Sitecore Meta with announcements too..

Comment: Can a moderator mark this with status-completed ? Thank you.